# Arabic grammar: The difference between the terms raf` and marfu'

Tags: terminology, grammar, arabic

I have begun to learn Arabic, and the difference between following terms confuse me.

There is this topic of `ʾirāb`—the science which deals with how the Arabic noun inflects with respect to its grammatical function within a given phrase, clause, or sentence. Within this topic comes `rafʿ`, `naṣb`, and `jar`. And then there is `marfūʿ`, `manṣūb`, and `majrūr`.

Taking, for example, `rafʿ` and `marfūʿ`, I understand that these are similar terms. But what is the *exact* difference?

Is this a correct understanding:`rafʿ` is the concept itself, and `marfūʿ` is the description of the noun which is a particular case of that concept?

Both `rafʿ` and `marfūʿ` are translated to English as `nominative case`. Perhaps this is the source of my confusion (that both are translated using the same words, because English does not differentiate between them): `rafʿ` is the name of `nominative case` as a “concept”, and `marfūʿ` is an actual noun *in* `nominative case`. If I am wrong, please explain.

Comment: You have spotted that the longer terms are all derived from the respective shorter terms, yes? And are all in the same grammatical form - probably a participle, but my Arabic grammar is very shaky.

Comment: Having looked it up, they appear to be _mafʿūl_, which is the passive participle from Stem I

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rafʿ is a noun and it means(among other things) "nominative case". marfūʿ is an adjective (passive participle) from the same root; it refers to a noun which is put in the nominative case.

Comment: @blackened Arabic has a tendency to "nounify" adjectives. Another noun/passive participle pair you'll eventually run into is كِتَاب‎ (kitab) which means writing as in a book, script or a body of writing and مَكْتُوب‎ (maktub) "that which has been written", which typically refers to a letter (as in mail).